# Copy everything inside element except its text content

Tags: jquery

Say, we have a nested structure of elements:

```
<div id="no1">
  <nav>
    <h1>text</h1>
    <h2>more text</h2>
  </nav>
  Even more text
</div>
```

How can I with jQuery copy *all* contained **elements** in this `<div>` and insert it into another `<div>` **stripped** from all text in all elements? To reach a result as this:

```
<div id="no2">
  <nav>
    <h1></h1>
    <h2></h2>
  </nav>
</div>
```

With jQuery, I can copy-paste all html inside an element:

```
var a = jQuery('#no1').html();
jQuery('#no2').html( a );
```

But how do I strip it from all its text - from all *non-element* content?

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "*non-element* content".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$(selector).text("")` to remove the text.  This will remove the text values of all the items in the selector (not just the first), so no need for `.each()`

```js
var h = $("#no1").html();
$("#no2").html(h);
$("#no2,#no2 *").text("");
// or, depending on meaning on "non-element content"
//$("#no2 *").text("");
```

```css
div { border: 1px dashed #ccc }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="no1">
  <nav>
    <h1>text</h1>
    <h2>more text</h2>
  </nav>
  Even more text
</div>
<hr/>
<div id="no2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let a = $('#no1').html();
$('#no2').html(a);
$('#no2, #no2 *').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE;
}).remove();
console.log(jQuery('#no2').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="no1">
  <nav>
    <h1>text</h1>
    <h2>more text</h2>
  </nav>
  Even more text
</div>
<div id="no2"></div>
```

Comment: While this solution does work, I actually prefer @freedomn-m's answer to my own.

Answer (score 1):

You can select all the children of the div and use the empty function like this:

```
$("#masterdiv").children().empty()
```